# Loop DELETE unnamed foreign key from a table

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I'd like to drop some foreign keys but unfortunately I did not name that constraint (and I mustn't edit that definition for my choice).

The definition of the table is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Disegnare(
        CF char(16),
        codCD int,

    --chiave primaria
    PRIMARY KEY(CF, codCD),

    --chiave esterna verso Persona
    FOREIGN KEY (CF) references Persona (CF),

    --chiave esterna verso class diagram
    FOREIGN KEY (codCD) references ClassDiagram (codCD)
);

/
```

I was looking for a tool which allows me to retrieve foreign keys' names in a table and delete them in order to add to that foreign keys `on delete cascade` statement using an `alter table` statement as the following:

```
ALTER TABLE Disegnare ADD CONSTRAINT fk_cf FOREIGN KEY (cf) REFERENCES Persona(cf) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE Disegnare ADD CONSTRAINT fk_codcd FOREIGN KEY (codcd) REFERENCES 
ClassDiagram(codCd) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

, so I tried the following:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
  (select constraint_name
   from user_constraints 
   where table_name = 'DISEGNARE' and constraint_type = 'R')
  LOOP
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement
        ('alter table "'||table_name||'" drop constraint "'||constraint_name||'";');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

(note that table `Disegnare` has two foreign keys, therefore I need to drop them)

But this return me the following errors:

> Report error -
>   ORA-06550: row 8, column 36:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'TABLE_NAME' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: row 7, column 5:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Does someone have ideas how to fix this?

Edit: I need to retrieve that names dinamically so that if I give the script to a friend of mine, he can do the same

Comment: Just to be clear: there is nothing wrong with the use of `dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement()` nor the generated dynamic string. The errors are simple PL/SQL syntax errors. **(1)** The projection of the driving cursor doesn't have all the columns needed (i.e. TABLE_NAME) . **(2)** The loop body code doesn't include the cursor name `c` when referencing the columns of the cursor projection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `table_name` column of `user_constraints` data dictionary view within the `SELECT` list and add qualifier `c.` for the cursor :

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
  (select *
   from user_constraints 
   where table_name = 'DISEGNARE' and constraint_type = 'R')
  LOOP
    execute immediate 
    'alter table '||c.table_name||' drop constraint '||c.constraint_name;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7c125f6709ae385256d23cd39a88cdf5)</kbd>

Comment: > ORA-01735:  ALTER TABLE not valid
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 593
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1134
ORA-06512: a "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 586
ORA-06512: a line 7
ORA-06512: a line 7
01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Comment: @Hiya you can alternatively use `execute immediate`

Comment: > ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option
> ORA-06512: a line 7
> ORA-06512: a line 7
> 01735. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Maybe I can't prefix constraint names

Comment: You just made my day. Thank you, sir. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Every constraint have name by default if it not provided explicitly, use `\d foo` or `\d+ foo` where `foo` is `schema.tableName` to show table structure and all constraints with their names

Comment: I need to retrieve that names dinamically so that a friend of mine which has my script can do the same

Comment: @Hiya you can compute constraint names, because you know the algorithm of name generation.

Comment: Can you please  provide an example of *"use `\d foo` or `\d+ foo`"* working for Oracle? Questions tagged `[oracle]` require solutions which are valid for Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `table_name` in your query. Either select it:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
  (select table_name, -- Here!
          constraint_name
   from user_constraints 
   where table_name = 'DISEGNARE' and constraint_type = 'R')
  LOOP
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement
        ('alter table "'||table_name||'" drop constraint "'||constraint_name||'";');
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Or, since you you have it hardcoded in the `where` clause, just hard code in the alter statement too:

```
BEGIN
  FOR c IN
  (select constraint_name
   from user_constraints 
   where table_name = 'DISEGNARE' and constraint_type = 'R')
  LOOP
    dbms_utility.exec_ddl_statement
        ('alter table "DISEGNARE" drop constraint "'||constraint_name||'";');
    -- Here -----------^
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This does not work:
> report error -
ORA-06550: riga 9, colonna 36:
PLS-00201: l'identificativo 'TABLE_NAME' deve essere dichiarato
ORA-06550: riga 8, colonna 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action: